# Showing count of total objects in Django template

Tags: django

I have a Djanjo project where I add code snippets to a database, I would like to show display, in my template, a count of total snippets.

Here is my model file:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Snippet(models.Model):
    snippet_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    code = models.TextField(default="null")
    approval_stage = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    updated = models.DateField('updated date')
    is_automated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.snippet_name

    def total_snippets(self):
        return snippet_name.count()
```

And here is the section of my template file where I want to display the number of snippets:

```
<h5>{{ total_snippets }} total snippets</h5>
```

This is rendering blank, with by value, on the final template. I've copied this code from another model, where I show a similar count of objects, and this works as expected, what am i missing here?

Comment: what did you write in views.py ? please include that

Comment: Can you please show your view. Just using `total_snippets` will *not* work, since this is a method.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem I realized that the code in my model file was redundant and that this value was actually being populated by code in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count all snippets with a specific name, this is what you're looking for:

```py
class Snippet(models.Model):
    ...
    def total_snippets(self):
        return Snippet.objects.filter(snippet_name=self.snippet_name).count()
```

Or to count all snippets in general:

```py
class Snippet(models.Model):
    ...
    def total_snippets(self):
        return Snippet.objects.all().count()
```